# Can I use or allow use of media keys on my website

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a music player on my website and have noticed spotify allows use of the media keys on my keyboard in their media player on their web version. How can I create a simple audio player that can use media keys?

I have made a music player that goes through tracks one after the other using:

```
<audio id="myVideo" controls autoplay>
    <source src="music.mp3" id="mp4Source" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
    <p> now playing <a id="nowplaying"></a> </p>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   var count=1;
    jQuery.get('./' + count + '/name.txt', function(data) {
        var songName = (data);
        document.getElementById("nowplaying").innerHTML = songName;
    });
   var player=document.getElementById('myVideo');
   var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');
   player.addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
   function myHandler(e)
   {
      if(!e) 
      {
         e = window.event; 
      }
      count++;
      $(mp4Vid).attr('src', "music"+count+".mp3");
      player.load();
      player.play();
   }
</script>
```

It works however the media keys cannot be used to replay the song or skip songs, any ideas or ways to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any useful resources until I did some further searching which I should've done before asking here, but nevertheless, behold, my perfect solution:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/media-session

it can be used like:

```
<audio id="myVideo" controls autoplay controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src="music.mp3" id="mp4Source" type="audio/mp3">
    Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
    <p> now playing <a id="nowplaying"></a> </p>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   var count=0;
    myHandler();

   var player=document.getElementById('myVideo');
   var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');
   player.addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
   function myHandler(e)
   {
      if(!e) 
      {
         e = window.event; 
      }
      count++;
       jQuery.get('./' + count + '/name.txt', function(data) {
        var songName = (data);
        document.getElementById("nowplaying").innerHTML = songName;

        if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {

  navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
    title: songName,
    artist: 'Artist Name',
    album: 'Album Name',
    artwork: [
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/96x96',   sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/128x128', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/192x192', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/256x256', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/384x384', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/512x512', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
    ]
  });

  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function() {document.getElementById("myVideo").play()});
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function() {document.getElementById("myVideo").pause()});
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', function() {});
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', function() {});
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function() {});
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', function() {myHandler();});
}

    });
      $(mp4Vid).attr('src', "music"+count+".mp3");
      var player=document.getElementById('myVideo');
      player.load();
      player.play();
   }
</script>
```